# Struggling with spring mvc deployment with static pages

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, tomcat

This is the first time i am trying to build a spring mvc app. This is how i have configured my spring app

**Project API Initializer**

```
public class ProjectApiInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {ProjectApiConfiguration.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }
}
```

**Configuration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.rootpackage.api")
public class ApiConfiguration {
}
```

Note that the spring mappings to `/`. Which is working fine when i access the url `localhost:8080/client/<client_id>/token`

**Controller**

```
@RestController
public class ApiController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/client/{clientId}/token", consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity getClientToken(@PathVariable String clientId){
        Message msg = new Message("hello " + clientId);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(msg, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

I don't have any `web.xml`. The api is accessible at the `localhost:8080/client/<client_id>/token`.

Now, I created a static html page in `webapp` folder and tried to access it at `localhost:8080/static_html.html` page but the tomcat returned `404`. Why ? What is i am missing here ?

Comment: Have you configured static resource handlers?

Comment: I have initializer and configuration ... no resource handler. What is it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should configure a resource handler, e.g.:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.rootpackage.api")
public class ApiConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
         registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("/public-resources/");
    }
}
```

Where "public-resources" is a folder / package in your JAR classpath.

Comment: I added this line in `addResourceHandlers` ... `registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/webapp/");` where my static html page is under `webapp` directory. When i tried to access it at `http://localhost:8080/<page_name>.html` it returned 404 ... though i do see the `doFilters` method being called.

Comment: Try .addResourceLocations("/"); instead

Comment: The `webapp` directory is not part of your war file. It represents a web application root. Put your files either directly into that directory or into any subdirectory and pass the respective path to `addResourceLocations` method as we recommended ("/" or "/dir-name/").

Answer (score 0):

Change your `ApiConfiguration` class as follows, put your static files under `static` folder within the web application root and try to access them via  http://localhost:8080/static/some-html.html.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.rootpackage.api")
public class ApiConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/static/");
    }

}
```